# Reset or change button title at the end of countdown

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, reset

I'm building an app for iPhone/iPad. My app has a countdown timer. The countdown start button is labled "Start", and it switches to "Running" when the button is pressed. When the countdown has reached 00:00, I want the button title to reset itself to "Start" or change it to "Restart", so that the user can start all over again.

I'm new to Swift, so I hope someone can help with this. Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class VC11 : UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!



    var timer = NSTimer()
    var count = 240
    var timerRunning = false
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


            func nextPage(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
                switch sender.direction {

                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                    print("SWIPED LEFT")
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seg11", sender: nil)
                default:
                    break

                }


                var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: Selector("nextPage"))
                var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: Selector("nextPage"))

                leftSwipe.direction = .Left
                rightSwipe.direction = .Right

                view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
                view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
            }


        }



    func updateTime() {
        count--

            let seconds = count % 60
            let minutes = (count / 60) % 60
            let hours = count / 3600
            let strHours = hours > 9 ? String(hours) : "0" + String(hours)
            let strMinutes = minutes > 9 ? String(minutes) : "0" + String(minutes)
            let strSeconds = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds) : "0" + String(seconds)
            if hours > 0 {
                timerLabel.text = "\(strHours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds)"
            }
            else {
                timerLabel.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds)"

        }
        stopTimer()


           }
  @IBAction func startTimer(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    sender.setTitle("Running...", forState: .Normal)

       }


    func stopTimer()

    {

        if count == 0 {
            timer.invalidate()
            timerRunning = false
            timerLabel.text = "04:00"
            playSound()
            count = 240

        }


    }




    func playSound() {

    var soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Metal_Gong", ofType: "wav")
    var soundURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath!)


        self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL, error: nil)
        self.audioPlayer.play()
    }


}
```

Comment: In your code I haven't found any button,where have you initialized your button.

Comment: You mean something like let button = UIButton(); where you set the size and color? I thought that IBAction was enough and set style via the Attributes Inspector. It works just fine (when I cklick on it, the countdown starts), except I can't figure out how to reset it. So yes, maybe something like that is missing.

Comment: do you have your button in storyboard or xib ?

Comment: main.storyboard - i only need to reset the title; resetting the seconds works fine with my solution. but maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, if you have button in storyBoard then just take outlet of the button from storyBoard, as you have taken for timerlabel, like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourButton: UIButton!
```

And then in your stopTimer() func just change the title of your button like this,

```
 func stopTimer()

{

    if count == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        timerRunning = false
        timerLabel.text = "04:00"
        playSound()
        count = 240
        yourButton.setTitle("Restart", forState: .Normal)// add this line in your code
    }
}
```